# Change MKAnnotation Pin Color

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I have an array of Meetup objects that display on a map as red pins. I would like to change the color of the pin based on an attribute of eachhe Meetup object. Each Meetup has a category. If the first Meetup in the array has a Category A, I would like the pin to be red, and if the second Meetup has a Category B, I would like the pin to be blue (And so on). I am trying to do this in viewForAnnotation.

Here is some of my code:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

  if annotation is Meetup {

    let identifier = "Location"
    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(identifier) as! MKPinAnnotationView!
    if annotationView == nil {
      annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)

      annotationView.enabled = true
      annotationView.canShowCallout = true
      annotationView.animatesDrop = false
      annotationView.pinTintColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 36/255, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
      annotationView.tintColor = UIColor(white: 0.0, alpha: 0.5)
```

I am trying to do something in here like:

```
if annotation is Meetup where Meetup.category == "Category A" {
          annotationView.pinTintColor = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 36/255, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
} else if annotation is Meetup where Meetup.category == "Category B" {
          annotationView.pinTintColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 36/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction on how to get this accomplished?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't you just want something like `if annotation is Meetup where annotation.category == "Category A" { ... }`?

Comment: Yes! However, when I add that it does not work. I don't think the annotation has the attribute of category. I can only access title, subtitle, or coordinate

Comment: You need some property to identify the category of the meetup associated with that annotation. Generally you would create an annotation subclass that included the category (or some other identifier by which you could determine the category).

Comment: Thanks! I will try this

Comment: @Rob since MKAnnotation is a Protocol and not a Class, is there a way to "Subclass" a Protocol?

Comment: You can either subclass `MKPointAnnotation` or create your own class that conforms to `MKAnnotation`.

Comment: @Rob thanks! I will try this

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are trying to change the pin color by category, You need to use "Switch" the actually code is like this:

```
func pinColor(type:String) -> UIColor{
var color = UIColor.purpleColor()
switch category {
case "Category A":
    color = UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 36/255, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
case "Category B":
    color = UIColor(red: 0, green: 36/255, blue: 255/255, alpha: 1)
default:
    color = UIColor.whiteColor()
}
return color
```

}

hope this is what you want!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Where I'm stuck is how do I get a reference to Meetup.category so that I can know which color to make the pin? Sorry if my question is not clear.

Comment: Hi @chickenparm, your array called Meetup right? and the structure is something  like Meetup(category: "Category A"),  Meetup(category: "Category"), then you use switch category to let pin know category's type domain the switch of color  and now you can decide the different pin colors with specific category. sorry english is not my native language, hope this can be help.